# How to find my current nginx.conf file from the AWS EC2 Enviroment

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need to modify nginx.conf to increase `client_max_body_size`  . On the AWS docs . Here they are giving an example of how to modify the configuration . but they are doing a lot more things that I don't want to do that.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-nginx.html

```
user                    nginx;
error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid                     /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_processes        auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile    33282;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  include       conf.d/*.conf;

  map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
      default     "upgrade";
  }

  server {
      listen        80 default_server;
      root /var/app/current/public;

      location / {
      }git pull
      

      location /api {
          proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:5000;
          proxy_http_version  1.1;

          proxy_set_header    Connection          $connection_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header    Upgrade             $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
          proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      }

      access_log    /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

      client_header_timeout 60;
      client_body_timeout   60;
      keepalive_timeout     60;
      gzip                  off;
      gzip_comp_level       4;

      # Include the Elastic Beanstalk generated locations
      include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/01_static.conf;
      include conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/healthd.conf;
  }
}
```

I need your help to decide what I have to put into that file so my other settings won't get affected. I pushed the code using elastic beanstalk and it running on the default python environment since then. So anyway to find my current `nginx.conf` file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to overwrite entire nginx.conf for that. As explained in the [Reverse proxy configuration docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html) you can just create `.platform/nginx/conf.d/myconfig.conf` file in your deployment package with the content of, e.g.:

```
client_max_body_size 10M;
```